# Science Fiction book with Three Part individuals

Tags: story-identification

All I can really remember is that an alien species has three member "individuals" and that three humans go to their home world posing as figures from the aliens' mythology.

As humans are a complete entity in and of themselves, this race is only considered complete when all three biological pieces are present together and acting in concert. A single biological entity acting on its own is considered aberrant.

Comment: Can you clarify this?   Do you mean the alien species only has three individuals in their entire race?

Comment: No... each "person" made of three individuals.

Comment: Please explain this better -- your downvotes may get reversed.

Comment: Well, in your comments, you've already started explaining it.

Comment: Does this involve children who are stranded on the world after a warring group of the aliens kills their parents, who were on a research exploration?

Comment: @SeanDuggan: I thought of the Tines in Vinge's [***A Fire Upon the Deep***](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Fire_Upon_the_Deep#Intelligent_species) also. IIRC, their units (for lack of a better word) usually had more than 3 "individual" members

Comment: It's been a while since I read it, but I think Isaac Asimov's "The Gods Themselves" has aliens with three sexes.

Comment: The Gods Themselves is the one. Thanks blm... I have been digging around trying to figure this out for nearly a month now.

Comment: Cool, glad that was it.

Comment: Darn I was going to try the gods themselves. Good show!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps **None But Man** by Gordon Dickson?

The Moldaug aliens are always part of a 3-alien group. They are humanoid aliens (*not* gaseous aliens such as in Asimov's The Gods Themselves). The Moldaug's scornful term for human being is "whiteface."

They have laid claim to the Pleiades. The idiot human negotiators try several conciliatory gestures which unfortunately have the opposite meaning to the Moldaug.

Our heroes travel to the Moldaug home world to re-enact a Moldaug legend, trying to explain the human situation in terms the Moldaug can understand (note that in Asimov's The Gods Themselves humans never ever travel to the alien homeworld).

Comment: The OP has posted a comment stating that Asimov's *The Gods Themselves* is the one he was looking for. Not having read either *The Gods Themselves* or *None But Man* myself, I can't say which one fits the posted description better.

Comment: I have read both books. "The Gods Themselves" does not have humans going to the alien home world and posing as figures from the alien's mythology. "None But Man" does. The OP can tell by the alien type: the aliens in "The Gods Themselves" are gaseous, the aliens in "None But Man" are humanoid.